# Using (boost) libraries on multiple pc, with same compiler/IDE version

Tags: visual-studio-2010, boost, compilation, static-libraries

This question has been bugging me since a long time already. I've been a bit reluctant to ask it as it is quite specific to boost (and my compiler), though I have to ask it someday or I'll never know it.

Anyways, I (as I guess many here) use multiple pcs, and use an external harddrive as means to easily access all data when "switching"; I have 2 laptops, and a desktop I regularly use. Now I stored all libraries (from boost) on my external harddrive, and I'm wondering if I can use them with multiple pcs?

The largest part of boost -header only libraries- can of course simply be used, but what about the extra parts that require compilation? I make sure all pcs are using the same version of IDE, so I think I should only compile them once? The IDE I use is visual studio 2010 (thinking of going 2012).

And what about the Qt libraries / extensions?

Comment: Just using the same IDE is probably not enough. You need to make sure all your systems have the same OS, same processor architecture, etc.

Why not just install Boost on all systems?

Comment: @KennethHoste well I quickly swap between pcs & simply use my projects from the external hard disk. It gets annoying remembering to update each and every pc (not to mention it is error prone). So I put all non-standard libraries inside my external harddrive, it's weird to have multiple boost directories on a single hard drive....

Comment: It doesn't have to be weird, or error prone.

I work in a team supporting a High Performance Computing system. We deal with problems like this all the time. To alleviate the error-prone issue, we built a software build and installation framework named EasyBuild (http://hpcugent.github.com/easybuild). It works tightly together with environment modules, which are often used in the HPC world, and which resolve the issue of having multiple builds/versions of a particular software package around.

Look into it, it might be what you're actually looking for (although we don't support Windows (yet)).